# How to retrieve the images from firebase storage according to the category of the images as wanted

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

How to Retrieve the images from firebase storage in which I have manually created folders according the category of my "wallpaper app" and I have created a list of "items" according to the category of my wallpaper. I am not understanding how to retrieve the images according to the "items"-(it is there in the code below) from the storage of firebase and display it accordingly.

I just want to store all the images according to the category of the "items" which is specified in the code below and display it in the app.

```swift
import UIKit
import GlidingCollection
import FirebaseStorage
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var glidingView: GlidingCollection!
    fileprivate var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    fileprivate var items = ["riches", "animals", "nature", "architecture","toys"]
    fileprivate var images: [[UIImage?]] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }
    func setup() {
        setupGlidingCollectionView()
        loadImages()
    }

    func setupGlidingCollectionView() {
        glidingView.dataSource = self

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CollectionCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView = glidingView.collectionView
        collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = glidingView.backgroundColor
    }
    func loadImages() {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let starsRef = storageRef.child("Animals")
        starsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("not there")
            } else {
                for item in self.items {
                    let imageURLs = FileManager.default.fileUrls(for: "jpeg", fileName: item)
                    var images: [UIImage?] = []
                    for url in imageURLs {
                        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { continue }
                        let image = UIImage(data: data)
                        images.append(image)
                    }
                    self.images.append(images)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Setup


// MARK: - CollectionView 
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
        let section = glidingView.expandedItemIndex
        let image = images[section][indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView.image = image
        cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true

        let layer = cell.layer
        let config = GlidingConfig.shared
        layer.shadowOffset = config.cardShadowOffset
        layer.shadowColor = config.cardShadowColor.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = config.cardShadowOpacity
        layer.shadowRadius = config.cardShadowRadius
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let section = glidingView.expandedItemIndex
        let item = indexPath.item
        print("Selected item #\(item) in section #\(section)")
    }
}

// MARK: - Gliding Collection 
extension ViewController: GlidingCollectionDatasource {

    func numberOfItems(in collection: GlidingCollection) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func glidingCollection(_ collection: GlidingCollection, itemAtIndex index: Int) -> String {
        return "– " + items[index]
    }
}
```

in another swift file linked to the cell of the collection view."CollectionCell.xib"

```swift
import UIKit

class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

}
```

I want all the images categorised and according to the items displayed in my app.

Comment: Could you please take a moment and format your code so it's readable (and not so long)?

Comment: How am i supposed to format the code. The code is already at its best

Comment: I added a section at the top of your question that says //formatted properly right after some code that is not properly formatted. Please properly format the code in your question using the formatting tools in the toolbar. It's really unreadable which is probably why you are not getting any responses. You should also include your Firebase structure (as text) in  your question so we know what you're trying to read. You may also consider reducing the amount of code. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay see my edit, using ``` for a minimal effort formatting.

Comment: Much better. However, the question is a bit unclear. It sounds like you are trying to read image from Firebase storage. To do that, the image URL's would be stored in Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore. You would get those URL's and then read in each image from storage. Can you clarify what the issue is as it looks like you know how to read an image already, if not see Storage [Download Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files)